# Difference between bindings file and jndi properties file

Tags: ibm-mq

Can you please let me know when to use .bindings file and when to use jndi properties file?

Answer (score 3):

The .bindings file is created by the JNDI FileSystem context (com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory) when data is stored by the MQ JMSAdmin tool or other JNDI tool. It contains a representation of the JNDI data, for example your Connection Factory settings such as hostname, port, etc.

In the case of MQ, the .bindings file is not used directly by MQ code, it is used by the JNDI code to create the MQ JMS objects which are then returned to the application.

The JNDI properties file (or the JMSAdmin.config file if you're using JMSAdmin) stores the connection settings to allow the JNDI code to connect to the JNDI repository (for example, the FileSystem context, LDAP server etc.). It does not contain data such as Connection Factory settings.